# Hook into "cd" change directory with emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm looking to load a local config file for emacs when I "M-x: cd" into a new directory.  Project specific settings.  I'm wondering how'd I'd set this up in my init.el.  I've got a local config setup like

(if (file-exists-p "~/.emacs.d/local.el")
    (load-file "~/.emacs.d/local.el"))

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't entirely clear, but one very useful technique for project-specific settings is to use a [`.dir-locals.el` file](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html):

> Sometimes, you may wish to define the same set of local variables to all the files in a certain directory and its subdirectories, such as the directory tree of a large software project. This can be accomplished with directory-local variables.

…

> Here's an example of a .dir-locals.el file:
>
> ```
> ((nil . ((indent-tabs-mode . t)
>          (fill-column . 80)))
>  (c-mode . ((c-file-style . "BSD")
>             (subdirs . nil)))
>  ("src/imported"
>   . ((nil . ((change-log-default-name
>               . "ChangeLog.local"))))))
> ```

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear to me what you're asking, but if you want to do something additional whenever Emacs function (command) `cd` is invoked then just advise it.